# Recode variable in multiples columns based on condition using function inside mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

I've this data :

```
    # A tibble: 169 x 5
   `Topical Anesthesist`             `Skin Glue`                   `Sedation Servi~ `Child Life Ther~ Hypnosis     
   <chr>                             <chr>                         <chr>            <chr>             <chr>        
 1 No, because we do not see/treat ~ No, because we do not see/tr~ No               No                No           
 2 No, we do not have one available  Yes                           No               No                No           
 3 Yes: LET/LAT (lidocaine, epineph~ Yes                           Yes              No                No           
 4 Yes: LET/LAT (lidocaine, epineph~ Yes                           Yes              No                No           
 5 Yes: LET/LAT (lidocaine, epineph~ Yes                           No               No                No           
 6 Yes: LET/LAT (lidocaine, epineph~ Yes                           Yes              No                Yes: during ~
 7 Yes: LET/LAT (lidocaine, epineph~ Yes                           Yes              No                Yes: during ~
 8 Yes: LET/LAT (lidocaine, epineph~ Yes                           Yes              No                Yes: during ~
 9 Yes: LET/LAT (lidocaine, epineph~ Yes                           Yes              No                Yes: during ~
10 Yes: LET/LAT (lidocaine, epineph~ Yes                           Yes              No                No
```

Depending on the columns, i've values with "yes", following by various characters chains ("yes, all day", "yes: during the whole day", etc ...). All my values begin by yes or no.
I want to replace every value beginning with yes by the word "Checked", and every value beginning with "No" with "Unchecked" ("Checked" and "Unchecked" are other values i use in the rest of my dataset and my code use them)

I try that :

```
data %>%
  mutate_all(.funs = fct_recode,
             "Checked" = starts_with("yes"),
             "Unchecked" = starts_with("no"))
```

I obtain this error :

> starts_with()` must be used within a *selecting* function.

I don't know how to simply solve my problem...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Convert your data to long format will be easier

Comment: Same error after use pivot_longer : data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 1:11, 
               names_to = "question") %>% 
  mutate_all(.funs = fct_recode,
             "Checked" = starts_with("yes"),
             "Unchecked" = starts_with("no"))

Comment: just do `mutate` on `question` column. Inside mutate you can use either `ifelse` or `case_when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code takes the starwars dataset, finds every  entry that begins with "bl" and replaces it with "HA":

```r
library(dplyr)
data(starwars)
func = function(x){
  ifelse(grepl("^bl",x), "HA", x)
}

mutate_all(starwars, func)
```

Following this pattern I suggest you try something like:

```r
func = function(x){
  ifelse(grepl("^Yes",x), "Checked", ifelse(grepl("^No",x), "Unchecked", x))
}
data %>% mutate_all(func)
```

Or more elegantly using `case_when`:

```r
func = function(x){
  case_when(grepl("^Yes", x) ~"Checked",
            grepl("^No", x) ~"Unchecked",
            TRUE ~as.character(x))
}

data %>% mutate_all(func)
```

Comment: I love this "case_when" idea. What an elegant solution :)

Comment: Thanks. A key limitation of `case_when` is that all the outputs have to be of the same type - hence the `as.character` in the final option.